# Error installing Mininet

Tags: linux, mininet

I get the following error when I try to install Mininet:

```
Installing Mininet core
~/mininet ~
cc -DVERSION=\"PYTHONPATH=. bin/mn --version\" mnexec.c -o mnexec
mnexec.c: In function ‘setns’:
mnexec.c:49: error: ‘__NR_setns’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I searched online and found that I could fix the problem by defining the missing system call number appropriately for my 32- or 64-bit kernel.

How do I define the missing system call number for the 32-bit kernel?

Comment: its late to reply but u should download latest version of mininet and install it.here is a link you can post your doubts [here](http://www.sdnexpress.com)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what `Mininet` is, but I believe your problem may be due to lack of a necessary header file. The error:

```
mnexec.c: In function ‘setns’: `mnexec.c:49: error: ‘__NR_setns’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Indicates that `__NR_setns` is not declared in what you are attempting to compile. A little digging shows the possible headers in which it is referenced in Linux. See [**Linux Cross Reference**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=__NR_setns). A short list of possibilities is:

```
/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h
/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h
/usr/include/bits/syscall.h
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-scnums-x86-linux.h
/usr/include/valgrind/vki/vki-scnums-amd64-linux.h
```

There are others, but those look the most relevant.